# explain about this code jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code to get value from scan barcode

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).focus();

    var coba=[];
    $(document).on('keypress',function(e){
        coba.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));                                    
        if (coba[coba.length-1]=="\r") {
          console.log(coba.join(''));  
          simpan(coba.join(''));
          coba = [];
        };
    }); 
});
```

anyone can explain about it?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Google is your friend. Start by Googling what each function means and then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you visit jquery.com and take a look at their api documentation and or their learning center.

Please see the comments embedded below.
This doesn't specifically do anything with barcodes

```
//this is waiting until the browser has loaded the page and all the content
// the elements in the content are considered the DOM.
$(document).ready(function() {

    //this sets the focus to the window, it acts as if you had clicked
    // on a blank spot of the window.
    $(document).focus();

    //this sets up an empty array to hold characters that are being typed
    var coba=[];

    //this sets up the page so that, when a key is pressed it does something
    //the anonymous function below is is executed when a key is pressed
    $(document).on('keypress',function(e){

        //adds the character that was pressed to the array
        coba.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));          

        //if the return key was pressed                          
        if (coba[coba.length-1]=="\r") {

          //print out the characters that were pressed on the browser console
          console.log(coba.join(''));  

          //this passes the string that was typed to a function
          // to a function named simpan -- can't tell you what that is
          // because it isn't a browser function.  Probably in a library
          simpan(coba.join(''));

          // empty out the array to wait for a new string to be typed
          coba = [];
        };
    }); 
});
```

if this is related to reading barcodes, what is likely to be happening is the barcode scanner that is attached to the system is acting like a keyboard.
The simpan function is probably provided by a javascript library, perhaps even one provided by the hardware manufacturer.

Good luck to you.